# Limiting row count to a specific number when inserting

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm thinking of implement a view history for my wordpress blog, where users can view their previously viewed articles as a list in their account page.

I would like to limit this to 24 unique page history per user at any point of time, meaning, if the number of articles exceeds 24, the oldest article row would be deleted, and the new article added to the table.

I'm using PHP and MySQL.

Here's my current thoughts on implementation:

- Create a table with user_id and post_id columns
- When user views an article, insert new row into the table
- Select the rows with the current user_id, and if number of rows is more than 24,
- Delete the oldest row

I'm not sure if this is the best method, since it's 3 additional database queries per user page view which is pretty heavy.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I would divide this into "time Critical" and "house keeping": Time critical is displaying the page, keep just the select but add a limit to 24 and an order by to get the latest. house Keeping you do behind the scenes in quiet time, delete all the > 24th rows per user. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ideea is good. Improve it by updating the oldest row instead of deleting it and then adding a new one. ;)
Also make a single read query and a single write query.

1. make a query that is like this one

   ```
   SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM recentArticles WHERE userID = 23)
   AS NoOfArticles, articleID, timestamp 
   FROM recentArticles 
   WHERE userID = 23 
   ORDER BY timestamp ASC 
   LIMIT 1;
   ```

If **NoOfArticles** < 24 then execute an insert query, else execute an update query to articleID

Comment: Thanks besciualex, Ronak and MaineCoder! Appreciate your fast responses. I'll take note of all the great suggestions, and see if there's any other options, and post back my solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could always implement this using cookies to key on which pages have been visited and keeping a running list on the users PC. This will reduce the traffic to the site, put the processing scripts on the user-side, and could be easier to implement.

That being said, I agree with the other answer about updating the oldest entry if the table is full. This eliminates the need to delete and add a row. Key off a time-date stamp to sort the entries when you're displaying them and to figure out which page was the oldest (and needs to be updated if >= 24 pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can merge two queries in one. In this way, You will save execution time of your script. So, basically, `DELETE` row if the post count is more than 24. You can modify this query according to your exact need. But yes, you can think on this way.

```
DELETE FROM `table_name`
WHERE id=(SELECT (CASE WHEN COUNT(id)>24 then id END)
          AS last_id
          FROM `table_name`
          WHERE user_id='XX'
          ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the sql, this really helps a lot!

Comment: I've tried this, the nested select actually returns the first id as the last_id, any idea?

Comment: try with `ORDER BY id ASC`.

Comment: I removed the ORDER BY and LIMIT, and it still always returns me that first id